# How to make Javascript console evaluate expressions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JavaScript but come from a functional programming background. In languages like Racket/Scheme there's a *definitions area*, where you write the program text and an *interactions area* where you have a REPL (where the values are displayed after evaluation).

Pressing the "Run" button with the following program:

```
(define-struct posn (x y))

(define p (posn 2 3))

(posn-x p)

(posn-y p)
```

Would yield the following results in the *interactions area (REPL)*:

```
2
3
>
```

I know there exists a REPL for node, so I can do the following:

```
~ node
> var p = { x : 2, y : 3};
undefined
> p.x
2
> p.y
3
>
```

If I write down the full text in a file and run the program, I get no result on the console (but I expected `undefined`, `2`, and `3` respectively).

```
var p = { x: 2, y: 3 };

p.x

p.y
```

```
node sample_program.js
```

Do I have to do `console.log(...)` whenever I want to see the value of an expression? Or is there a way to actually evaluate the expressions?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a debugger. Visual Studio Code has a free node debugger that I don't think requires any setup. Webstorm as well (webstorm is not free).

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in a js file, you need to do console.log() to output the value to the browser console.

If you just want to have a REPL like feature then use the browser console to write the code and it will evaluate expressions

Lastly, if you really want to output from a file, you could write a shorter version of console.log() if it's too much typing

```
function print(str) {
    console.log(str);
}

//Now use print

print(p.x);
print(p.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome you can type expressions directly into the console for evaluation, it'll work like a standard REPL except the code from the page you're currently on is already loaded there. Option-Command-J to open the JS console on Chrome.

Comment: For Windows users: `Ctrl + Shift + J`

Comment: I'm usually a Linux user myself, can't believe I wrote the Mac bindings...